# How would people muzzle a siren? What would it look like?

Tags: merfolk

My sirens have mostly humanoid upper halves, and since it's the Victorian era, surgically altering their vocal cords isn't really an option. These are pets for very bold people, but very dangerous if they are allowed to sing.
They have fine-tuned ears, sharp teeth, and are pretty strong—especially in the water where they are not weighed down.

Comment: How similar are they to humans? What is their level of intelligence? Can they talk, and, if so, in what language? Have they developed a culture? How large are they? Do they need water to survive - should they be kept in aquariums?

Comment: They've got intelligence close to a teen's, and the can speak, they have their own, but they can also learn human languages through mimicry. They don't really have a culture, the females are very aggressive. They don't breathe air, but they can live in an aquarium of there's moving water.

Comment: They're also about human sized, the males being smaller, and the females are larger.

Comment: If they don't breath air, how do they produce song - what's the apparatus that need muzzling? We'd need that detail in order to answer.

Comment: "_intelligence close to a teen's_" and "_don't really have a culture_" doesn't quite gel for me. Dolphins and orcas can certainly play games and even have "fashions", of a sort, and your beasties are at least as intelligent and have manual dexterity.

Comment: They are highly aggressive, and while there is pecking orders within the pods females form, they don't have emotions like we do. Things like remorse, joy, love, they don't feel. 
To sing, they force air from their lungs into their throats and vocal cords. But, they need to be able to open their mouths to sing, or it'll be far to quiet and muffled to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

## Pick a gag, any gag

The goal is to make it impossible to sing or bite, but let them still breathe, drink, and make other sounds. To that end, what you want is a gag. There's a number of varieties that might work here, such as a ring gag, a ball gag, or a spider gag, but since you specify that you're dealing with strong creatures with sharp teeth, I recommend a strapless steel gag, operated via set screws:

[image]

<sup>Credit to EclipseMetalworks on Etsy</sup>

This:

- Prevents the siren being able to cut any straps holding the device in place
- Leaves the mouth open
- Allows the siren to pass water through their mouth to operate their gills, if any
- Is fairly resistant to water damage, though if you keep them in a brine pool, replacing the set screws with a more robust, rust-resistant locking system might be prudent

It causes jaw pain and cramping over the long-term, and may cause some pain, but hey, sirens are animals, and you're a Victorian, so you don't care.

Alternatively, if you want to cover the mouth or keep it closed, a standard face harness and muzzle should be adequate:

[image]

<sup>Credit to the [Wikimedia Foundation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Muzzle_gag2.jpg)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

***Make them lose their voice on their own***

The concept is simple, overwork their vocal chords. Choose a caretaker(tank cleaner, feeder, whatever) who is deaf and has been given specific instructions to watch the siren for cues for when they're trying to sing and act like their songs are working but put up some measure of 'resistance' and eventually break out of the 'trance' each and every time. The siren will be confused about this person who seems to be resistant to their songs and will try harder and harder to ensnare them, the caretaker going along with the act slightly longer each time as the siren overworks their vocal chords and eventually loses their voice entirely. They can still make sounds, they'll just be restricted to what a person with an overworked voice is usually restricted to and as such will not be able to sing and ensnare others any longer. Whenever it seems like their voice is returning go through the process again.

Once/if they get wise to the trick, or if you simply want to cut straight to business, then I'd recommend a gag that not only keeps them from biting such as what has been proposed by Daniel B, but also removes the ability of the vocal chords to articulate entirely by shoving a somewhat flexible rubber tube down their throats and forcing the vocal chords to remain at their widest aperatures, allowing breathing, drinking, even eating if you mush their food for them(bite prevention gag won't allow them to chew), but singing will be out of the question. If the muscles involved with their vocal chords remain out of use for long enough they may even atrophy, eventually allowing you to dispense with the need for the tube.

Tongue-based vocalizations and articulations will still be available depending on how you go about it, but I doubt that'll be enough for the sirens to work their magic. If it is enough then, well, the knife is always an option.